# Moving mouse to edge of screen pans the desktop out of view

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, fonts

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and roughly 50% of the time when I log into my account, the fonts in the GUI are not smoothed/antialiased. Furthermore, when moving the mouse the the right edge of the screen, the desktop pans across the screen and a large black space appears on the monitor.

I have attached two screenshots, the first is not entirely accurate because on my monitor the black area is on the other side of the screen. Notice the unsmoothed fonts in the menu.

The second shows the correct appearance of the fonts and moving the mouse to the edge of the screen does not pan.

**My question is: is this a known bug and is there a solution or workaround to prevent this from happening other than logging out/in?**

My graphics card is a nVidia GT630 on Nvidia binary driver 331.113 if it could be graphics related.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vwMB.jpg]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5IVN.png]

Answer (score 0):

I have Ubuntu same as yours, and an nvidia gt820. I've used an extra screen with my laptop before and experienced none of the issues you face.

I would do these steps.
Check to see if you're using latest Ubuntu updates
Check you installed the graphics drivers using additional driver settings in Ubuntu.

Its hard to say for certainty, but it might be a problem with your drivers installed.

How did you install your driver?

Comment: This is a desktop machine, one monitor via VGA + one TV/monitor via HDMI (although not switched on - wondering if this could be an issue). Drivers are up to date, installed via the 'Additional Drivers' control panel.